# practical use case of Binary tree zig zag traversal

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Are there any practical use cases of binary tree zig zag traversal? 
Is there any use case where we need top view, bottom view, left view and boundary nodes of a binary tree? I am interested to know these questions for interviews or are there any other practical uses of knowing it.

Comment: For reference, I've taught advanced courses in data structures and courses in algorithm design and have never heard of this before, and all the sites I've found for it seem to from programming-competition-type sites. I'm going to assume it's fairly contrived and more of a "write a variation on BFS" type exercise than a practical technique.